# Unable to record Coded UI tests in Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Microsoft came up with a solution to support Coded UI tests in Silverlight 4 applications.
Proposed solution in 2 steps and I did it. Steps are:

1. Install Visual studion 2010 feature pack 2.
2. Added SilverlightAutomationHealper.dll to my Silverlight 4 project.

   I build the project and tried to record CUI tests but failed. I found an error message

"No Silverlight controls were detected. Verify that the application under test is built using Silverlight assemblies wiht a version of 4.O or greater and that a reference to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll assembly has been added to the project. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204562" raised.

This issue really annoying us, can anyone plese help me.

Thanks,
Jaji Alapati.

Answer (score 1):

If your controls are named correctly (x:Name), then an other issue might be there with the test execution. If you use Internet Explorer to run tests, you have to run IE in compatibility mode (turn the compatibility mode on in the URL section of the browser). This might solve your problem.